# Jetty JDBCLoginService role based access not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jetty

This is a follow up from this post: [Jetty JDBCLoginService using null in mysql request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220290/jetty-jdbcloginservice-using-null-in-mysql-request) where you can find the realm configuration.

I'm using jetty JDBCLoginService to do the authorization in my app,
i have, of course, value in my database.
the authorization part of my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>
    Areas with authentication required
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern> /protected/* </url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee> NONE </transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>gateway_jndi</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/public/login.jsf</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/public/login.jsf</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

the login part of my backingbean:

```
public void login() {
        ExternalContext    externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request         = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        try {
            Faces.login(getUsername(), getPassword());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(request.getContextPath() + "/protected/statistiques.jsf");
            } 
        catch (ServletException ex) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(
                "formMsg", 
                new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
                        messagesBundle.getString("main.gateway.title.error"), 
                        messagesBundle.getString("main.gateway.common.controller.error.login")
                        )
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setPassword(null);
    }
```

While using it i always get a 403 with !role in the console, if i use ** i can log into the app.

I am missing something in my backing bean or is the problem jetty related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i was wissing the roles in my web.xml, eg:

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
```

it seems:

```
<auth-constraint>
 <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

means any role kown to the app, not any role in the database.